# Do Stack Overflow staff programmers ask questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

The title mostly explains what I was curious. I am guessing that Stack Overflow has a number of programmers working on SO site itself.

The questions is, can SO programmers use SO to get their answers, as their question might potentially reveal a security hole, or point out the flaws in the site implementation?

**Edit:**

The `duplicate question` that was linked to this question, has the selected answer:

> Yes, we do.

And here the answer was:

> No.
>
> I never asked anything on Stack Overflow.

So it is basically not the duplicate question in its terms, as the answer is different :P

Comment: Are you specifically referring to questions about programming problems that occur within the SO codebase?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to those situations.

Comment: Well, there's a non-zero chance any of Marc's recent questions could be based on such a problem even they make no explicit references to the codebase... there's probably also a chance that a question exists *with* explicit references to the codebase - though I'd imagine for the sake of keeping questions reasonably scoped they'd still adapt the code and text somewhat. After all, even if you have a programming problem that no one else has had before, chances are someone else is going to benefit from the answer in the future - and that's what Stack Overflow is all about.

Comment: _"as their question might potentially reveal a security hole, or point out the flaws in the site implementation?"_ - I think you can expect someone who's hired as a developer for Stack Overflow to be capable enough of creating a MCVE that doesn't expose any exploitable details...

Comment: That assumption can't be true no matter how someone is trying to write good code. Remember that [Microsoft bug](http://securityintelligence.com/ibm-x-force-researcher-finds-significant-vulnerability-in-microsoft-windows/#.VGNwwPnF-Sq) which was there since '95 :) or better in this [image](https://securityintelligence.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/CVE-2014-6332-Example.jpg) ;)

Comment: I'm not saying Stack Overflow developers don't write bugs, I'm saying you can expect them to know how to write a MCVE.

Comment: There's the recurring joke that SO developers have the hardest job, because if their site goes down they have to fix it without SO.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No.

I never [asked anything on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded?tab=questions) ;-)

Nor has [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=questions), or [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell?tab=questions), or [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver?tab=questions)...

---

We are software developers, not software encyclopedias - of course we use the site... Some more than others.

Comment: One question remains: Do you still have your  Experts-Exchange account?

Comment: I imagine if they did they wouldn't be working at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @rene - I have never needed their services in gender reassignment, never had an account there.

Comment: So [did @rene just assume](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/did-you-just-assume-my-gender) your need for such services?

Comment: Was just curious. Who knows, you newer know what might be the policy for the ones making the actual changes to the site. Thanks Oded and @BoltClock

Comment:  Stack Overflow programmers are not the gods of programming? You broke my world @Oded

Comment: Well, there is Jeff Atwood's sock puppet account *[Eggs McLaren](http://stackoverflow.com/users/8/eggs-mclaren)*.